# Mysql- Select data that has been uploaded more than 2 months

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where I upload the users galleries. 
I need the users with the gallery.created_at has been uploaded for 2 or more months.
I have tried this but it is giving me 0 results

```
    select `galleries`.`client_id` as `client_id`, 
        `users`.`first_name` as `first_name` from `galleries` 
        inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `galleries`.`client_id` 
        where `galleries`.`session_id` is null and 
       `galleries`.`is_video` = '1' and `galleries`.`is_thumb` = '1' and
        galleries.created_at >= galleries.created_at - INTERVAL 2 MONTH 
   `galleries`.`client_id` not in (select `client_id` from 
        `orders`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
galleries.created_at >= galleries.created_at - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

and a missing `AND`.

Perhaps `curdate` is what you need:

```
select g.client_id as client_id,
    u.first_name as first_name
from galleries g
inner join users u on u.id = g.client_id
where g.session_id is null
    and g.is_video = '1'
    and g.is_thumb = '1'
    and g.created_at <= curdate() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    and g.client_id not in (
        select client_id
        from orders
        )
```

I used `<=` because your requirements states *uploaded for 2 or more months*.

Comment: Tried that, it returns me the data between `galleries.created_at` and crrent_date - 2 months i.e. 15th Feb-2017.
I need the data where galleries.created_at is more than 2 months old

Comment: @baig772 - You need `<=` as you said in the question - `uploaded for 2 or more months`

Comment: @baig772 - Do you really have data in that period? what is the type of the created_at column?

Comment: Yes I have. data type is timestamp

Comment: I would suggest removing the other filters one-by-one to see if there's a separate issue.